# Как сделать так, чтобы выражение могло объявляться не константой?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Как исправить ошибку "выражение должно иметь константное значение" в 14-ой строке? Visual Studio выдаёт эту ошибку, а онлайн компиллятор online-cpp без проблем проигрывает этот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int sum1;
    int sum;
    int n = 0;
    string p;
    cin >> p;

    char chars[p.length() + 1];
    p.copy(chars, p.length() + 1);
    cin >> sum >> sum1;
    for (n; n <= 17; n++) {
        if (n < 9) {
            cout << n + 1 << " | " << p[n] << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << n + 1 << "| " << p[n] << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << "-----" << endl << sum1 << "/" << sum;
}
```

Comment: Используйте вектор.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выделять память динамически:

```
char * chars = new char[p.length() + 1];
```

Ну, а потом не забыть `delete[] chars;`

Comment: Плохой совет. Везде где в C++ нужен массив не фиксированной длины, надо использовать `vector`. Другие способы возможны, но только после того как вы убедились что вектор не решает вашу задачу.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy *"Как исправить ошибку "выражение должно иметь константное значение" в 14-ой строке?"*, а не "как решить задачу в духе С++". Кстати, обратите внимание, что `chars`, в общем-то, в коде и не используется... Так что ***для чего*** использовать вектор?...

Comment: Моя мысль о том что если вы пишите `new`, остановитесь и подумайте не сделает ли ту же работу вектор лучше? В подавляющем большинстве случаев вектор оказывается лучшим решением (даже по производительности).

Comment: Я бы скорее обратил внимание на то, что нет никакой проверки длины введенной строки, при том что цикл с фиксированным значением `for (n; n <= 17; n++)`, т.е. очень вероятен выход за границы массива. Это мне кажется более важным.